# How to stay signed in even after clicking refresh button

Tags: php, html

I am new to php and I want to add a functionality such that whenever user fills the form and logs in, the php code runs perfectly fine but after refreshing the page user have to again fill the form. I don't know code nor have knowledge of further.I tried googling but I only see these kind of solutions:

header(refresh: 5, url: url);
or
meta tag

That refreshes automatically but not after clicking the refresh button.

This is my php code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="services.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap-css/bootstrap.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap-3.3.5-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="validate.js"></script>
    <style>
        a{
            color: dodgerblue;
        }
        a:hover{
            color: dodgerblue;
            font-size: 101%;
        }
        span{
            font-size: 110%;
            line-height: 8px;
            font-style: bold;
            margin-left: 50px;
        }
        body{
            background-color: #F0F0F0 ;
        }
        button{
            margin-left: 15px;
        }
    </style>
</head> 
    <body link="slateblue">
        <div id="LogIn"><b>Log In</b></div><br>
        <form method="post" onsubmit="return logInPass()" action="log.php">
            <div class="col-xs-4"/>
              <label for="usr">Email:</label>
              <input id="usrEmail" name="usrEmail" type="email" class="form-control" size="25%" placeholder="sample@example.com"/>
            </div>
            <br><br><br><br>
            <div id="PasswordField" class="col-xs-4"/>
                <label for="u_pswd">Password:</label>
                <input id="u_pswd" type="password" class="form-control" size="25%" placeholder="Enter alteast 8 characters" />
            </div>
            <br><br><br><br>
            <button id="submit" name="checkout" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="submit">Log In</button>
        </form>
        <br><br>
        <a href="SignUpForm.html" target="form"><span>Not a part of GameRangers? Click here for Sign Up!</span></a>
        <br>
    </body>
</html>


  <?php 
    echo "<style>body{font-family: segoe ui; font-size: 110%;}</style>";
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['usrEmail'];
    echo"Welcome  ".$_SESSION['username']."<br><br>";
    echo "Today is ".date("Y-m-d")."<br>".date("h:i:sa")."<br>";
?>
```

Comment: there isn't enough code here

Comment: As per your edit: you're outputting before header.

Comment: I actually have removed the header.It didn't make out.Any strong suggestions?

Comment: You need to show us your full code for all pages, including the html form. I also posted an answer (20+ mins ago, as of this comment), but you haven't commented on it, nor do I know if that worked for you or not.

Comment: log.php: https://www.dropbox.com/s/gc0ybrpfk8z9mog/log.php?dl=0 logInForm.html : https://www.dropbox.com/s/l05rz9e3f4z3r6j/LogInForm.html?dl=0

Comment: please add the code to your question, thank you

Comment: By contemplating much I guess I have to change value of attribute "action" after signing/logging in.If I'm on right track then tell me how to do it in php.

Answer (score 0):

Use SESSION or COOKIES to store logged in status

On successful sign in, set a session variable or cookie.

Then check if the session variable or cookie is isset and is the intented value, then keep the user on the page. Otherwise, redirect to login.

Also keep session_start() at the beginning of the page.

---

**Edits to make it clear for the OP**

Add `session_start()` at the beginning of the page. After validating the username and password, if an existing user, set a session using the below code.

```
$_SESSION['u_name'] = $_POST['usrEmail'];
```

otherwise, redirect to login page.

Then on top of all user specific pages (the pages that are accessible only to logged in users) paste the below code.

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['u_name']))
{
   header('location:login.php?redirect='.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
   exit;
}
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: This really is a comment

Comment: will then I be able to stay on mypage.php?

Comment: Yes. Make sure you store the value to the correct session variable or cookie, and then check whether its isset and not null. Otherwise, redirect to login page.

Comment: " if the session variable or cookie is isset and is the intented value, then keep the user on the page.." that's what I don't know how to do so.

Comment: I have updated my answer with the method using session variable. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

use `sessions`:

```
session_start();   // in top of PHP file
...
$_SESSION["userName"] = $userName;
```

in your page

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION["userName"]) && $_SESSION["userName"] != ''){
 //redirect to logged in page
}
```

Comment: I've used the very same as you can see in my code but after giving a refresh, instead of php code form loads out.Obviously I don't want to again fill the details.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you're outputting before header with the location of `session_start();`.

Place it as your first line under your opening `<?php` tag, and you're missing an underscore in `$SESSION` and for `$SESSION['username']`, it is a [superglobal](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php).

- The session isn't being recorded/stored because of it.
- Sidenote: I'm really hoping that wasn't a typo on your part.

That should read as `$_SESSION['username']`

Having used error reporting, would have signaled a notice of an undefined variable.

Make sure that `$_POST['usrEmail']` also holds a value and the element bears the same name attribute, and that the session is started inside all pages using sessions and with no typos as you have now.

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Displaying errors should only be done in staging, and never production.

---

If you want to retain session values in a form, use a ternary operator for the inputs:

```
<input type="text" name= "usrEmail" id="usrEmail" value="<?php echo !empty(htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['username'])) ? htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['username']) : ''; ?>">
```

...and apply that same method to your other form inputs.

Check to see if the session is set and not empty.

```
<?php 
session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

    if(isset($_SESSION["userName"]) && !empty($_SESSION["userName"]) )
    {
        // do something
    }

    else{
        // do something else
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

as you are using sessions to store user name . This session can be used in if condition as like i had used here:

```
<div id="nav1">
 <?php session_start();
            if($_SESSION['id']=='')
            {
            ?>
            <font style="font-size:16px; font-weight:bold; color:#063443;">Welcome, Guest&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="Login.php" >SignIn</a></font>
            <?php }
            else
            { ?>
            <font style="font-size:16px; font-weight:bold; color:#063443;">Welcome, <?php echo $_SESSION['name'];?> &nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="signout.php" >SignOut</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="accinfo.php">My Account</a></font>


<?php }
?></div>
```

Here i had stored User Id in session[id] which will make a condition to show user login or not.